# How do I securely delete cookies and saved passwords?

Tags: firefox, passwords, safari, privacy, cookies

Is there a way, from inside Firefox or Safari, to delete cookies and saved passwords in such a way that the data is unrecoverable (similar to Secure Empty Trash)?

Or do they already do this out of the box?

I know I can probably track down all the files involved and then manually clean them up, but I'm curious if there's an easier way.

Answer (score 3):

you can use ccleaner (you can find it with searching at google or you can downlaod it from filehippo ... ccleaner can delete all extra(temproary) information that stored in computer or just specific programs files like cookies of firefox or internet explorer ... (i do not understand whta you want exactly i mean if you want to erase all cookies etc. (for firefox) you can go to tools that select 'clear recent history' select everything from time range and also at bottom there is an options what to delete, select desired options then clear now thats all i guess you cleared all cookies etc.. ((but ccleaner is very useful program i am using that program for more then 4-5 years ;)

Comment: Does CCleaner __securely__ delete files?  http://www.apple.com/pro/tips/empty_trash.html

Comment: Never mind, I was able to find some more information, indicating that it does in fact have a "secure delete" option:  http://forum.piriform.com/index.php?showtopic=9281

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, even tracking files is not really really secure.

Files get (physically) written here and there... they get out of control.

If it's really that sensitive to you, better mount /home/username/.mozilla directly as an encrypted filesystem (e.g. encfs or ecryptfs).

Instead of deleting, what you will do is you will create a brand new filesystem with a brand new encryption key, copy the current profile from a mounted 
with the sqlite file, and securely delete the encryption key of the previous filesystem. Without the key then it's really garanteed never to be recovered.

(I'm assuming Firefox really enforces that this database file will not contain traces of the stuff you have deleted.)

Sorry, your question is about a user-friendly approach, and my answer is that even the non-user-friendly methods may be unsecure depending on what level of security you need.

Answer (score 0):

all the cookies and pwds are saved in sqlite database file . when you delete cookies /pwords the approprate table entries are deleted in the sqllite file.
you may want to delete the firefox profile directory manually  using secure delete programs.

Comment: Hi Srin.  Thanks for your answer.  This is kind of what I meant by "I know I can probably track down all the files involved..." :-).  I'm looking for something that works inside the browser and already "knows" about all these files.

Answer (score 0):

Use the folowing hotkey:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd>

Delete whatever you want !

Comment: Why -1? In firefox I regularly use this combination to delete cookies, cache, browsing history etc. It is different from ctrl+ALT+delete.